# Time Series Stationary or Not

Tags: time-series, stationarity, heteroscedasticity

Here is my time series plot of some data. There appears to be a constant variance, but I don't believe that the mean is constant (e.g., big dip around time $t=17$ and big increase around time $t = 57$). Is it correct for me to say that this time series does not have a constant mean, but it does have a constant variance? I am a beginner to time series analysis.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are a beginner to the time Sseries topic: I would advise you to someone, who has the same charm as Josh Starmer:

He is known under the channel ritvikmath:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oY-j2Wof51c&t=6s

You should check if your series is stationary by applying visual, global/local tests of rolling windows (e.g. mean,variance) but the better would be a statistical test. Thus, I would advise you to check this video, and the video on

> white noise

If you then still dont know how to deal with your time series, we are pleased to help you. But I would advise to first look into a few of his incredible vids.